# Attaching new plugin to $ or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I wrote a plugin ( which uses jquery).

Should I attach it to the  jquery's dollar sign ?

`$.myPlugin=...` **or should I** attach it to  `window.myPlugin=...` ?

Of course this plugins won't work without jQuery . but does it mean that I should create a GOD object($) and attach everything to it  ( to the dollar sign). ?

*(assuming `$` is single library object on the page)*

Comment: rather attach it to `jQuery`

Comment: @VeXii read my last line.

Comment: ain´t this qustion abit subjective? its going to work none the less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the jQuery site, you should attach it to the `jQuery` object, not even to the `$` (which may or may not be reused). See http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ .

Note that the typical pattern is to use the `$` as an alias within the definition:

```
(function ( $ ) {

// jQuery recommends avoiding more than one instance method, instead taking
//   a parameter, or better yet, an extensible options object:
$.fn.instanceMethod = function(options) {
  //...
  return this;
};
$.classMethod = function () {
  //....
};

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Ok, but the answer is still attach it to the jQuery object, not to a global (as well as don't unnecessarily define your own global `$` alias of any kind as the plug-in).

Answer (score 1):

If your plugin relies on jQuery, it is a good practice to attach it to `$` sign (or `jQuery`).
You can safely do this when using IIFE (immediately invoked function expression)

```
(function($){
   // you code here that does $.myPlugin=...
})(jquery);
```

Comment: attaching objects to window is not consider a good idea (creates clutter). You can always have your own namespace under $ like `$.myProject.myPlugin1` and so on